# By updating Flutter 3.8.0 Error in flutter_date_time_picker

Tags: flutter, flutter-datetime-picker

By updating Flutter 3.8.0
I am getting the following error in flutter_date_time_picker.
I would like to know if anyone knows a solution to this problem.

```
../../../../.pub-cache/git/flutter_datetime_picker-eb66486c47d50bf550950c196486121ffcea8885/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:7:1: Error:
'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.
```

pubspeck.yaml

```
  flutter_datetime_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker.git
```

If anyone knows of a solution, I would love to hear about it.

I believe this is probably due to the flutter update, as I was able to build normally until yesterday!
If anyone knows of a solution, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: Remove this import statement. 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart'

Comment: Anything update here? What solution is solve to you? I also face that error. Adding prefix cause dependency conflict error.

Answer (score 11):

you may use

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker_plus

It is a Forked from (Pub) flutter_datetime_picker as it had issues with dart 3.0

Comment: indeed, worked for me

Answer (score 3):

you can also use this package "flutter_datetime_picker_plus"

[https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker_plus/install][1]

it works exactly like flutter_datetimer_picker you just have to install and that's all.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker_plus/install

Answer (score 2):

#### Name Clash

This error:

`'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both`

is telling us two classes imported into the current file from different packages *have the same name*.

Dart cannot tell which to use, hence the error.

#### Two common solutions

1. `hide` (don't import) one of the classes
2. Apply a prefix to one of the packages

#### Hide

Here's an example of hiding a single class from being imported from a package:

```
import 'package:text_widgets/text_widgets.dart' hide TextThemeExt;
```

Above the class named `TextThemeExt` won't be imported and won't clash with an identically named class in the current file.

#### Prefix

`import 'dart:math' as math;`

This is a very common prefix applied to the `math` library in dart. (So people reading the code understand these are symbols from the `math` library and not some short variable name in the current file.)

Any symbol within the `math` library now must be prefixed with `math` to be used.

For example:

```
Matrix4.rotationX(math.pi)
```

Without the prefix in the import statement the above would be:

```
Matrix4.rotationX(pi)
```

#### Summary

In this particular case, the author of the package chose a name for a class they created that conflicts with the name of a class in the Flutter Material package, which is a pretty essential package for most Flutter devs.

In the [proposed fix](https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/pull/317/files/8c893f8594763d96f9b0f83eeb5db164299fdc1d), a person offered to `hide` Flutter's `DatePickerTheme` class from being imported.

If you're using this package from this author, there's not much for you to do besides wait for them to merge the change and publish a new version of their package.

Answer (score 2):

using an alias on importing package works for me. I'm using material an flutter_datetime_picker in same dart file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue caused by Material and flutter_datetime_picker sharing names. It can be solved by adding an alias to your import then specifying which plugin is being used:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart' as PluginDatetimePicker;
```

Then when calling your objects in your code you must specify that it is coming from PluginDatetimePicker:

```
PluginDatetimePicker.DatePicker.showDatePicker(
     context,
     locale: PluginDatetimePicker.LocaleType.en,
     theme: PluginDatetimePicker.DatePickerTheme(
            headerColor: headerColorX,
            backgroundColor: backgroundColorX,
            itemStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 22),
            doneStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
     ), 
     onConfirm: (date) {
         // onConfirm()
     });
```

Comment: For anyone coming back to this answer due to the flutter_datetime_picker package, the package author is inactive and the project has been forked as flutter_datetime_picker_bdaya by another publisher that is keeping standards

Answer (score 0):

first try to flutter clean and then pub get and reinstall the package you want. if again you had this error try this:
To resolve it; in the class where you have both imports, assign an alias to one of the packages using the as keyword.

```
import 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' as dp
dp.EveryMethodYouWant(); //call the class using the alias
```

if you had any question i'm here.

happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

By mistakenly,you have imported the wrong package because as per the package documentation, there is no such line mentioned.

Import the package mentioned below and try pub get.

import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';

everything vill works fine.